# Angular include page but keep relative paths in the included page's original directory

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, relative-path, angularjs-ng-include

Currently, my company is trying to switch completely over to AngularJS. We have used it to some degree for about 2 years but our code base has primarily been in PHP.

The PHP files are in a directory named "php" and the AngularJS files are in one named "angular"

I need to be able to include the PHP pages onto an AngularJS page.

I have been able to accomplish this just fine...however, the relative paths for things like images, php includes, script includes, etc. are now trying to find the files in the "angular" folder...which will not exist. I'd like it to still look within the "php" folder to find the files.

I am aware that we **could**:

- Include the PHP page in an iframe
- Get the contents from the server, then place it on the AngularJS page
- Change the PHP page's paths from relative to absolute

I do not like those solutions though and would like to avoid them if at all possible. Especially changing the relative paths to absolute paths...as we have far too many pages that would need to be updated.

Is it possible for me to use ngInclude, or some other AngularJS alternative, to place the PHP page on the AngularJS page but keep the included PHP page's paths inside the "php" folder? Or am I just going to have to suck it up and do one of the aforementioned?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It does not matter how you load your scripts relative paths are going to be relative to browser. I think the best thing you could do is some Mod_Rewrite hacks if you're using Apachee.

Comment: Yeah i thought about that as well earlier but I'm not sure how it would be accomplished since some of the same named folders exist in both folders. I'll give it some thought though, thanks!

Comment: Well if there are same named folders, than this is why you get paid :P

Comment: Very true! Thank you for the suggestion!